# Only way to change a word is with span?

Tags: html, css

I am changing a word on my site to a different font than the rest of my text. The only way I know to do this is:

```
<p>My text here <span class="myclass">then word to change</span> more text</p>
```

Is there a better way to change that or is this the only way?

The reason i ask is because in I can do something like this:

```
img[src*="name of file"] {
    /*my style here*/
}
```

While my text does not have its own tag I did not know if there was a way I was missing.

Comment: "better way"?  What could possibly be better?  It's not the only way, but it's often the best.  The alternatives can be horrifying.  What's the problem with `<span>`?  What don't you like?  Please be **specific** in your question.

Comment: @S.Lott I edited question to reflect a bit better what I am asking and mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware this would be the most logical way to do this. CSS loads fast and having one class and the chance of it being used multiple times on a page means for a good load time.

Also, if you ever decide to change the colour/style with a redesign then it's easily modified.

Comment: In adition, there are some fine tools like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ that might help the OP to easily replace / add content on existing files.

Answer (score 1):

That is the recommended way, especially for HTML4+

Answer (score 1):

Is your word contained in a paragraph of text or is it sitting in its own html tag? If the latter is the case, then you can define the class like you did for the span tag and write the css/ javascript on that tag directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an achor tag with no href and some css.

```
<a class="myclass">My Word</a>
```

Comment: True, but span would be just as easy. => On top of that it would pickup my link styling which I could override with my class but not worth the effort.

Comment: Using the wrong kind of tag often leads to problems with accessibility and cross-browser functionality. Different platforms often make somewhat-reasonable assumptions based on tags, and if one thinks you have an anchor, it may introduce unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

"Better" is a subjective term. If you want to be more semantic, you can use  tags instead of  tags to indicate that you want the text to have emphasis. This also carries the additional benefit of having 2 fewer letters for you to type. :-) If you don't care so much about semantics, you can even  or  tags to save 1 more character.